# How to use generated HTML in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Why is it that when I copy the HTML generated by vue in inspect element all @click event is gone ?

Does anyone have idea how vue works ?

Comment: I already put the build.js in html file.

Comment: Why java and spring-boot tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not really clear... But what I can say is that Vue.js use something call virtual DOM. So what you code is not what is showed in the browser.

You can read this article for more details : https://medium.com/js-dojo/whats-the-deal-with-vue-s-virtual-dom-3ed4fc0dbb20

Comment: Yeah I think your answer is correct , do you have any idea on how I can make this work ? Right now we are trying to render page using the html that is generated by the vue. How can I get the event ?

Comment: In Vue , event are calling methods. So you have to bind an events to one of your html elements, and define a method. This link will give you all the details : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: actually, the case is I want to use a build.js file generated by webpack as a normal js file in an html page, is this even possible?

Comment: Yes it is the way it work. With vue js you create you app by creating multiple components, including modules etc... and then webpack will build your app and put everything in a single .js file. So all you have to do is to add this single .js into your html.

Comment: I have an existing system that is created in vue. What I want to achieve is from that I will copy the html by inspect element and put the html in another system also the build.js is this even possible to work ? The html and css is now working well , but when I click the button that supposed to be have events are now not working anymore.